# How to get all securities in an asset class from IBPy (Interactive Brokers python API)

Tags: interactive-brokers

Would like to know how to request all securities in an asset class using IBpy, the python wrapper for the Interactive Brokers API.

For example getting all currency pairs in the class forex ('CASH'), or all stocks in the class equity ('STK').

Current efforts: Searched QF stack, stackoverflow and IBPy's google discussion groups.
Ongoing efforts: Trawling through IBPy's "ibConection" class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't via the API. If you need to search use the contract lookup database

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/?f=%2Fen%2Fgeneral%2Fcontact%2FtipsContractsDatabaseSearch.php%3Fib_entity%3Dllc

Comment: Thanks for the reply pyCthon. I've taken a look at it and it does indeed let me check what I require. Would you recommend me automating this process? Or just manually update the members of an asset class. Appreciate any input/advice.